# How to format time durations for media clips {audio, video, music, science etc}

Tags: formatting, date-and-time, units, video

Mathematica has powerful date, time and timeseries functions and options.
Yet they all seem to be tightly tied to Time in global clock-calendar-astronomic perception.

I need to do basic time-duration arithmetic and plotting for media clips..

For example: I have sequence of video clips:

```
v01 = 25m14s
v02 = 2h23m00s
v03 = 1h    

v01and02 = v01 + v02
videostotalTime = v01 + v02 +v03
```

etc

help: I cannot find simple syntax for this in Mathematica

How to format and add/subtract/multiply my data in SIMPLEST most legible manner to give me totals, sub-totals, duration offsets, lists etc?

I tried

```
v01 = TimeObject[{0,25,14}]
v02 = TimeObject[{2,23,00}]
v01 + v02 is what I want <<< but does not give me duration sum.
```

I have been looking in docs and googling, but am missing basic keywords/concept

thank you

Comment: here is how red-lang does it

http://www.red-by-example.org/#timexex

Comment: Try `Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{25, 14}], MixedUnit[{"Minutes", "Seconds"}]]`

Comment: Can you just use `Quantity`? I.e. v01 = Quantity[25, "Minutes"] + Quantity[14, "Seconds"]

Comment: thanks^ 
... I really want a much more concise syntax :: easier to read and write, not just for me, but for interop workflow chain
others <p>

Comment: ..and for other people {who are unfamiliar with mathematica}.   I spent a few days digging into red-lang [v nice but new-- see http://www.red-by-example.org/#timexex].  Then dug into emacs **orgmode** which is mature and does all the math right -- and inside tables.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679867/calculating-duration-in-org-mode-table     http://orgmode.org/manual/Durations-and-time-values.html 
  >> model orgmode, then hope to emulate in Mathematica